# EntityFramework connection string in referencing project's web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have two projects in my solution: an ASP.NET MVC web app project with a `web.config` per environment (production/UAT/dev) and another DAL class library project referenced by the web project that uses EntityFramework Database First to handle persistence. At the moment, the DAL class library project has its own `App.Config` that specifies the connection string to be used.

I require different connection strings (or rather, different `data source`) for the different environments.

How would I go about moving the connection strings to the `web.config` in the the web project and referencing them from the DAL project at runtime?

The auto-generated EF `Model.Context.cs` code that currently references the connection string name is [name changed for anonymity]:

```
public EodActivityEntities()
    : base("name=DatabaseNameEntities")
{
}
```

Comment: No matter which application you run as your startup project, only one `app.config` or `web.config` will be read and used by that application.  If you need different connection strings for each of the applications, you will have to manage those independently of one another.  If you call the connection string by the same name (`DatabaseNameEntities`) in each config, it will be picked up at run time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your application will only ever read a single `app.config` or `web.config` at run time which will be the one from your start-up project.

Therefore if you have the following in your DAL:

```
public EodActivityEntities()
    : base("name=DatabaseNameEntities")
{
}
```

... and you run your web application as your start-up project, it will pick up the connection string with name `DatabaseNameEntities` from that project's `web.config`, ignoring what is in your DAL `app.config`.  So it's already doing that for you.  Therefore I would say that you shouldn't need to have your connection string in your DAL's `app.config` file at all.

Now, for the different environments you want different connection strings.  Create new Solution Configurations for your environments DEV, UAT & LIVE and you can use `web.config` transformations (info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326(v=vs.110).aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd465318(v=vs.100).aspx)) and it will build with the correct connections strings.

Comment: Thanks mate. Does the app.config in my DAL project get used at all then? It has some EF-specific configuration...if I deleted it can I expect everything to still compile and run fine?

Comment: No problem.  Yes I'm pretty sure that you can delete it and everything will be fine.  I personally don't delete them because you never know I might need to re-create them in the future :).  Only the calling app.config gets used, it's unlikely that you're going to use your DAL as the calling project in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend passing the connection string in the constructor of your context. The base constructor created by EF takes a string and can either be a named value from a configuration file or simply the connection string itself.

Then move your connection strings per environment to the MVC project where you can instantiate the context using values in it's `web.config`

```
var connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connection"];
var context = new EodActivityEntities(connectionString);
```

Coulton is correct in that only one configuration file will be loaded, and a solution could be to name the connection strings the same so that the web.config will load when you run the application. However, this is spreading your configuration around rather than pushing that to the context root of the application.

Answer (score 1):

When you reference your DAL project from your Web project, the built DAL.dll should automatically be copied into the /bin folder of your Web project at the time the Web project is built. First, check that is indeed happening. If not, look at the Web project References, find your DAL project in the list and view the properties. CopyLocal should be set to True.

When your Web project is running, any reference made by your DAL to settings that would have come from your DAL's app.config, will instead come from your Web app's web.config, as the DAL will be running under the context of the Web application.

So you are right, that you need to add settings to your web.config.
The best way to utilise different values for different environments is to use web.config transforms. In a Web application, you may already have a couple of these as child solution files sat under your web.config (web.debug.config & web.release.config). Visual Studio will apply these transformations when publishing. We typically have a publish profile for each environment and a matching transform file for each environment, but only one actual web.config file with all the default (untransformed) settings in.

You didn't mention which version of Visual Studio you are using, but this article may help you along the way: 
http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/web-config-transformations

This explains further: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=125889